# respond_with won't work on nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've this code that I'm trying to get working.

```
class CommitRequestsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @commit_request = CommitRequest.new(params[:commit_request])
    respond_with(repository, @commit_request)
  end

  private
  def repository
    Repository.find(params[:repository_id])
  end
end
```

I also have this spec

```
CommitRequest.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
post(:create, { 
  format: "json", 
  repository_id: repository.id, 
  commit_request: {}
})
response.status.should_not eq(201)
```

The problem is that the spec is always failing.
It returns 201, even tho the created object isn't valid.
Removing the mock line results in the same problem, 
even tho the created object is invalid (for real this time).

I'm using Rails 3.2.